# Ios - the itunes connect showed no build in test flight after i use application loader to upload my ipa

Tags: ios

i am using the application loader to upload my ipa to the ios, however after i upload it does not show anything to enable me to check the status or see any build in the test flight, i uploaded yesterday and now still not able to test flight with anyone. Morever after i reupload and it wrote that the application already existing online and unable to upload, anyone face the same issue with me?

Comment: Did you try just changing the build number and re-uploading?

Comment: @WilliamGP yes , i changed d, and now it seem to have something appeared now , i will see if this solve the problem